# Creating a meridian globe vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, 3d

I'm looking to recreate a simple vector image of a globe with meridians in Illustrator CS5. I tried using the Revolve tool and then applying a grid as Map art, but the result was weak.

I know I can just use a wireframe shading option, but I figure there might be another, more effective way. Is there?

[image]

Edit: here's the result with CS5. Meh. [image]

Comment: Your current attempt looks fine to me, just add more grid lines of you want it closer to the first example.

Comment: What exactly is the problem as far as i can tell those satisfy your description. Is the upper image what you want to make? If not it would be nice to know what your after so show a image that looks like what your goal is. What could possibly be more effective than a magic plugin that does 99% of the work? Whats the problem with it?

Comment: Notice how the lines warp: thicker around the equator of the globe, thinner as they approach the pole. But you guys are right, I guess I can just further refine it myself, after expanding it.

Comment: This is very easy to accomplish in the completely free LaTeX where you have a bunch of packages that can do this for you. You can then expand the generated PDF for further refinement in AI.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [pst-3dplot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot?lang=en) package available for example in [Texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). Oh look, they've got what you want as an example right in the manual. If you want to have perspectivity, try [pst-solides3d](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d?lang=en) instead.

Just in case you don't know how to handle this all by yourself, you can use this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/5730371btcymj) to access one such example. The code is very easy to understand.

[image]

Comment: Well, yes there are tons of free software that can do this with much less disk overhead than any tex package. I either case he is 3 clicks away of what he asks even inside illustrator so i dont see much gain here

Comment: @joojaa then I would like to know these free softwares too.

Comment: Well im not in front of my computer until sunday so i can not make a list. but this is pretty easy to do in python and matplotlib (maybe double your lines), benefit is that its interactive like illustrator and exports vectors and can be made to account for perspective.  There are about 20 other free tools that can do the same with or without charting info. But again illustrator allready knows how to do this all one has to do is not make his map out of strokes and apply strokes after an expand. So by paging out your doubling the workload.

Comment: @joojaa then you should probably mention this to him, with more details.

Comment: He allready said he would do that. He was just looking for a shortcut but given that all avenues were equal or more work nobody bothered to answer.

Comment: @joojaa his method does not work well. You proposed a slightly different approach which could probably help. But I just don't get what you mean by applying stroke after one expand. Do you mind exlaining?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42811/discussion-between-joojaa-and-troy-woo).